# Flutter textField doesn't work properly in a table

Tags: flutter

I have some text fields in a table that aren't working properly.  Code in dartpad is at the link below.  I have a two column table by three rows.  The right hand column has a TextField in each row.  For some unknown reason, only the first row will accept the focus and allow me to enter text.  On dartpad I can get from the first row text field to the second row by using the TAB key but not by tapping on the text field in the second or third rows.  On a real device there is no tab key.  Does anyone know why only the first row works?

Similarly with the leftmost column I have a GestureDetector wrapping a container but onTap only works for the first row and not for rows two and three.  Why does only the first row work?

In the supplied code there  is  getTableRow3, getTableRow2 and getTableRow1 of which only getTableRow3 is being called - it is the simplest version of the three.

https://dartpad.dev/?id=977fbdaf851bf86f0b51965393a1e4fa

Comment: It does look like there is some element overlapping those text areas and because of that, you cannot click them. As you can move down and edit the bottom ones with TAB and arrow keys.

Comment: Thanks. I found that I had a sized box wrapping the table that was too small - it allowed the table to be visible but prevented being tapped on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had a sized box wrapping the table that was too small - it allowed the table to be visible but prevented being tapped on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).